# How to simulate slow queries on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scripting, mongodb-3.6, bash

I need to write a shell script that finds and kills long running mongodb queries, but I don't have access to the database that runs slow queries, how to I simulate running slow queries on my local machine running mongodb v3.6.8, so that I get some relevant output from db.currentOp() for now doesn't return much, also any tips are welcomed for the script as well.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/12908425/2002471 work for you?

Comment: You could use [db.fsyncLock()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/index.html), however, then you must use an update command (e.g. insert, delete, update) rather than a `find`