# Shell Script to kill slow running Mongo Queries

Tags: mongodb, scripting, mongodb-3.6

I need to create a shell script that finds and kills long running mongo queries more than a specified threshold e.g. 15sec I plan to use db.currentOp(); and db.killOp(); to find and kill queries but I do not have much experience with shell scripts. how do I do this?

Comment: Please post your questions only once: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286913/how-to-simulate-slow-queries-on-mongodb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate slow queries on MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286913/how-to-simulate-slow-queries-on-mongodb)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit these questions are different one is about simulating slow queries, as in how do i get my mongo queries to take more time in getting me the result, other is how to properly find and kill query, I had provided script detail in other question just for a bit more context

Answer (score 3):

Just putting this here since I was struggling with the same for a while:

Here is how you can do it in python3
Tested on mongo version 4.0 and pymongo version 3.11.4

```python
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017")
admin_db = client.get_database("admin")

milliseconds_running = 10000

query = [
    {"$currentOp": {"allUsers": True, "idleSessions": True}},
    {
        "$match": {
            "active": True,
            "microsecs_running": {
                "$gte": milliseconds_running * 1000
            },
            "ns": {"$in": ["mydb.collection1", "mydb.collection2"]},
            "op": {"$in": ["query"]},
        }
    },
]

ops = admin_db.aggregate(query)

count = 0

for op in ops:

    admin_db.command({"killOp": 1, "op": op["opid"]})

    count += 1

logging.info("ops found: %d" % count)
```

I wrote a more robust and configurable script for it  [here](https://github.com/Kasahs/mongokillslow) 
It also has a Dockerfile file in case anyone wants to use this as a container. I am currently using it as a periodic cleanup job.